# Farseer Physics: How to create shape from Vertices?

Tags: c#, xna, farseer-physics-engine

As you can understand from the title, I'm pretty new to game development. I'm doing this for fun. Anyway here's my question.

I have this Farseer Physics samples and i've been studying them for a few days. One thing i can't understand is, how the vertices creates the shape? I mean, in the game sample, where you create a shape for your car from vertices, there is a code like this:

```
Vertices vertices = new Vertices(8);
vertices.Add(new Vector2(-2.6f, 0.10f));
vertices.Add(new Vector2(-2.375f, -0.46f));
vertices.Add(new Vector2(-0.58f, -0.92f));
vertices.Add(new Vector2(0.46f, -0.72f));
vertices.Add(new Vector2(2.7f, -0.07f));
vertices.Add(new Vector2(2.5f, 0.205f));
vertices.Add(new Vector2(2.3f, 0.23f));
vertices.Add(new Vector2(-2.55f, 0.35f));

PolygonShape chassis = new PolygonShape(vertices, 2f);
```

I understand you create a vertices list and add 8 points(?) to it and then you make a polygonshape from those vertices, a random shape created from your points(?). The thing i can't understand is what are those numbers which inside the Vectors? I mean where in the shape are those? Corners? Edges? or a line between those two floats? Or the line between the corners?

Now lets say I want to make a shape like this

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ac7Dv.png

What are those vertices for this picture?
You can give random numbers thats not a problem, only thing I want to understand is, what are those Vectors on this picture? Thank you very much for your help and time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Vector2`, in this case, represents a [position in 2D space](http://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_coordinate_system). The first number you pass to the constructor is a position along the X-axis, and the second is a position along the Y-axis.

(You can also use `Vector2` to represent the relative displacement between two positions, or a direction and a magnitude - as in a velocity.)

The `Vertices` class from Farseer Physics represents a closed shape. That shape is made of of a list vectors (it derives from `List<Vector2>`). `Vertices` interprets its list of vectors as a list of *vertices* (to use the technical term). That is to say: **`Vertices` is a list of *positions* that form the *corners* of a polygon**.

`Vertices` represents a closed shape. So there are implied straight edges between each vertex and the one following it, and between the first and the last vertex.

Furthermore, many parts of Farseer expect shapes to be defined in counter-clockwise order (in standard Cartesian space, with the Y-axis pointing *upwards* - this differs from Client space, which is used for drawing by `SpriteBatch`, where the Y axis points down). Fortunately `Vertices` provides `IsCounterClockWise` and `ForceCounterClockWise` to help ensure your shapes are defined in the correct order.

The `PolygonShape` class is essentially a wrapper `Vertices`, which allows Farseer to differentiate it from other possible shapes, like `CircleShape`.

(For context: A `Body` provides position, rotation, velocity, etc, and has one or more `Fixture`s. A `Fixture` provides friction, collision detection, etc, and has a `Shape`. If that `Shape` is a `PolygonShape`, then it will have `Vertices`.)

Comment: Thank you very much for this clear answer. This is exacly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Those points describe the perimeter of the polygon. For your random shape those would be

(-10, -10), (10, -10), (-15,10) (15, 10)